# How do I find all connected input devices in a native activity?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

In my android native activity, I would like to find all of the game controllers connected to the android device.

In input.h, there is a comment above AInputEvent_getDeviceId() that says

```
/*
* An input device id of 0 indicates that the event didn't come from a physical device;
* other numbers are arbitrary and you shouldn't depend on the values.
* Use the provided input device query API to obtain information about input devices.
*/
```

Does anyone know which "provided input device query API" the comment is referring to?

If I can't find all the connected devices, then maybe I can wait until AKEYCODE_BUTTON_START is pressed, and then assign that device as Player1...

Thanks!